# Get all triggers that call a certain function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger, postgresql-9.6

So an insert violates a constraint because a trigger modifies the data when it shouldn't for this case.

Thing is, I already disabled the triggers that I thought were causing this, and the function still gets called.

How do I best get the triggers I'm missing?

Note that the function is called WITHIN the trigger function, so

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE action_statement LIKE '%my_function%';
```

returns nothing;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find which trigger uses a certain trigger function, query the catalog:

```
SELECT tgname,
       tgrelid::regclass
FROM pg_trigger
WHERE tgfoid = 'my_trigger_function'::regproc;
```

If the function you are talking about is not the trigger function proper, but called from a trigger function, things are more difficult.

Since functions in languages other than `c` and `internal` are stored as strings, PostgreSQL doesn't track dependencies between functions.

So the best you can do in that case is a substring search:

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure
FROM pg_proc
WHERE prosrc ILIKE '%myfuncname%';
```

Comment: Hm ... not quite what I'm looking for.
I have multiple different triggers calling the same function internally.

Comment: Oh, functions calling functions. You are pretty lost then, because PostgreSQL doesn't track dependencies between functions. The best you can do is to search the `prosrc` column in `pg_proc` for string matches...

Comment: "It might be the actual source code of the function for interpreted languages" ... If that covers plpgsql, that could actually work. (Not tried yet.) Do you want to expand the comment into an answer?

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
select routine_name, routine_schema
 from information_schema.routines 
 where routine_definition ~ 'the_evil_one'
 and data_type = 'trigger';
```

I hope that it will work for you provided that the trigger routine's languge is plpgsql.